# Apple Service and Support Coverage Query with PHP CURL

Tags: php, ios, curl, post, web

I want to make query with PHP CURL on the site: [Apple Service and Support Coverage](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/) and want to get result with a Serial No/IMEI No `(example IMEI: 359209071801769)`.

How can I do this. Any ideas?

With the code below I didn't get any result because I couldn't post the value. Any idea?

```
<?php
    $cookie = "cookie.txt";

    if(!$_POST){
    $curl = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://checkcoverage.apple.com/gc?t=image&timestamp=".round((microtime(true) * 1000) - (60*60*3/1000)));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://checkcoverage.apple.com/tr/tr/"); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    $gv = curl_exec($curl);

    $sadf = json_decode($gv, true);

    echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$sadf["binaryValue"].'" /><br />';
    echo 'Type Captcha Code <input type="text" name="captcha" /><br />';
    echo 'Type IMEI<input type="text" name="imei" /><br />';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Run" />';
    echo '</form>';
    curl_close($curl);
    }else{
    $imei = $_POST["imei"];
    $captcha = $_POST["captcha"];

    $curl = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://checkcoverage.apple.com/tr/tr/");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://checkcoverage.apple.com/tr/tr/"); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    preg_match('#csrfToken\: "(.*?)"#si', curl_exec($curl), $token);
    $post = "sno=$imei&ans=$captcha&captchaMode=image&CSRFToken=".$token[1]; 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $content = preg_replace("/<head.*>/i", "<head><base href='https://checkcoverage.apple.com/' />", curl_exec($curl), 1);

    if(curl_exec($curl) === false){ 
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl); 
    }else{ 

    echo $content;
    } 
    curl_close($curl);
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use empty for encoding instead of gzip. If you specify gzip then it will only handle gzip, where as if you specify empty it will handle all.

   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
2. Use full path for your cookie instead of absolute path. i.e `$cookie = "/var/some/cookie.txt"`
3. Use [http_build_query](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for post parameters instead of raw parameters (in case if there is any special character in your post parameters).
4. Run the code using verbose enabled to see what is happening with your curl.

   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

Comment: I did what you said to my code but no success. I have no special character in my post parameters. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Could you please correct my code and post here or try my code and take a look again ?